# problem in using path.combine statement in c#

Tags: c#

```
    string targetPath = @"C:\Program Files\saadhvi\SetupSafetyPADUniversal\";
    string createDatabasesScriptFilePath = Path.Combine(targetPath, "\\EADBScripts\\CreateDatabases.sql");
```

i am getting the value of createDatabasesScriptFilePath is \EADBScripts\CreateDatabases.sql

but i expected it would be C:\Program Files\saadhvi\SetupSafetyPADUniversal\EADBScripts\CreateDatabases.sql

what is the wrong with my code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the first \ from the string "\EADBScripts\CreateDatabases.sql"

I'm not completely sure of the reason, but a I guess Path.Combine wants as second parameter a relative path, and a relative Path does not start with a \.

Answer (score 16):

Here is why your code is returning the 2nd path (copied from MSDN help) -

*If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator character. If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.*

Answer (score 2):

Remove the initial backslash from "\EADBScripts..." in the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
string targetPath = @"C:\Program Files\saadhvi\SetupSafetyPADUniversal\"; 
string createDatabasesScriptFilePath;
createDatabasesScriptFilePath= Path.Combine(targetPath, "EADBScripts\\CreateDatabases.sql");
```